# Iterating Through a Folder of Files

Tags: python, file, loops, directory

I work in the office of one of the professors at my college and he has assigned me to read through a whole classes papers to attempt to catch people that plagiarize so I decided to write a program using python that looks at all of the six word phrases in all the papers, and compares them to see if any of the papers have over 200 matching phrases. The six word phrases would be for example...

**I ate a potato and it was good.** Would be:

I ate a potato and it

ate a potato and it was

a potato and it was good.

My code is corrently

```
import re

def ReadFile(Filename):
    try:
        F = open(Filename)
        F2=F.read()
    except IOError:
        print("Can't open file:",Filename)
        return []
    F3=re.sub("[^a-z ]","",F2.lower())
    return F3
def listEm(BigString):
    list1=[]
    list1.extend(BigString.split(' '))
    return list1


Name = input ('Name of file? ')
Words = ReadFile(Name)

Words2= listEm(Words)
index1=0
index2=6
new_list=[]

while index2 <= len(Words2):
    new_list.append(Words2[index1:index2])
    index1 += 1
    index2 +=1

print (new_list)
```

I am able to create all of the six word phrases for a single file in the folder, but am confused on how to do so with every file in the folder and how I would go about comparing them. Any and all help is much appreciated and Thanks from a first semester Comp Science major.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate over the files in a directory like so:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):  #choose files will be found in this case anything.txt
    with open(file) as f:
        #code...
```

The documentation on glob can be found here: [Glob PyDoc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob)

You would want to go through all the files and construct a record of all the phrases. Though you would need to keep track of which phrases came from where, because on the second pass through the files checking for the phrases the phrase which was recorded in the first pass will be found in the same file on the second pass. You'll need a way to only look for phrases which came from other files.

This code will create files called badphrases_.txt which have a list of phrases:

```
import glob
import itertools

for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    with open(file) as f:
        with open('badphrases_%s' % file,'w+') as bad_list:
            text = f.read().split() #get all the words
            bad_list.write('\n'.join(( ' '.join(text[i:i+6]) for i in range(0,len(text)-5,1) )))
```

For example if 'b.txt' contained 'I ate a potato and it was good.' the generated file would contain:

```
I ate a potato and it
ate a potato and it was
a potato and it was good.
```

From here, you may want to remove punctuation. From this point you just need to check each file for the contents of any badphrases_name.txt files where name != the current name of the file being checked.

**Explanation**

```
for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):
```

is a generic for loop, which *traverses* all values contained in the result of

```
list(glob.glob('*.txt'))
```

the syntax for the for loop is [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

In this case, the target_list is 'file', the expression_list is `list(glob.glob('*.txt')`. The else/suite part is an optional construct,
the code block 'suite' will be executed if the for loop isn't terminated within it's suite of code. For example

```
for i in range(10):
    pass
else:
    print("No errors!")
```

yields:

```
>>> 
No errors!
```

while

```
for i in range(10):
    break
else:
    print("No errors!")
```

won't enter the `else` clause and consequently nothing is printed out.

Now, what is `glob.glob('*.txt')` doing? This method inside the module 'glob' will find all the files in the directory that match a pattern, in this case: *.txt (the * represents anything). The reason we convert it to a list using `list()` is that `glob.glob()` is a generator. And since we are creating a file inside the loop, `glob.glob` will pick it up later. I.e

1. Open file `a.txt`
2. Make file `bad_phrases_a.txt`
3. `glob.glob` might then return `bad_phrases_a.txt`
4. Make file `bad_phrases_bad_phrases_a.txt`

As you can see this process would result in infinite recursion, hence we want to exhaust the generator before we start creating the *bad_phrases* text files. `list()` will get all the values `glob.glob('*.txt')` returns and put them in a list like so: `['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']`. We then use the for loop to examine each one in sequence.

`with open(file) as f:`

This code opens the current text file whose path is stored in `file` (from the for loop) and assigns it to the variable `f`. We use f to write text to the .txt file itself. The *with* syntax is a construct which in the case will close the file once we're done with it. You can read more about the with syntax here [With Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

```
with open('badphrases_%s' % file,'w+') as bad_list:
```

Similar to above, we open a file as bad__list. `'badphrases_%s' % file` is a string substitution. it places the values after the `%` into the string preceeding it **in order**. In this case `file` represents the name of the file we're currently looking at.

```
text = f.read().split()
```

`f.read()` pulls the contents out of the file  and into memory and stores it as a string. the `.split()` method creates a list of all the words in the file, i.e: `['ate','there',...]`.

```
bad_list.write('\n'.join(( ' '.join(text[i:i+6]) for i in range(0,len(text)-5,1) )))
```

The main section above is where it all happens. `write()` outputs text to the file. Working outwards:

```
( ' '.join(text[i:i+6]) for i in range(0,len(text)-5,1) )
```

Is a generator expression. It is similar to a list comprehension i.e: 
`[x for x in range(5)]`would produce`[0,1,2,3,4]`. the `join()` method takes an iterable and joins the content together and between each element puts a character, so `'*'.join(['a','b','c']) == "a*b*c"`. In this case we want to select six words `text[i:i+6]` and combine them into one string, where each word is separated by a space `' '`. We do this for values of i from 0, up to the number of words in the text - 5 and at each step we increment i by 1.

This creates a list of lines we want to print to the file. So we use `'\n'.join(...)` to combine each of the lines into one string where each line is separated by a new-line (represented by the '\n').

Comment: For each file in the folder given to me by the professor, would it be possible to run my program to find all the phrases, and then create a file of those phrases to put into a new folder? Like given 25 papers, find the phrases for each paper, and for each paper create a file of the lists of phrases and put that file in a new folder so in the end you would have a new folder containing 25 files of the word phrases?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a solution to the problem as we speak. My main concern is that with 25 papers, looking at phrases 6 long, then working out the combinations for each phrase, will add to a huge amount of phrases. The program will take a long time to run. Are there any constrains you would like to introduce? I'm happy to have a go at making a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your request, I see now that what you wanted was simply all the segments 6 words long starting at the beginning.

Comment: My apologies I should have made things more clear! Thanks for all the help I really appreciate it

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't completely understand your solution. Would it be possible for you to show me a way to implement it into my current code? Sorry I'm a Python noobie.

Comment: I'll write up an explanation for you if you'd like?

Comment: That would be absolutely amazing if you could